# How is this timestamp file generated from maven build?

Tags: maven

I was working on a maven project and this project is generating some weird file.
The file name are like:

```
[PROJECT]/target/classes.531226305.timestamp
[PROJECT]/target/classes.1241815416.timestamp
[PROJECT]/target/test-classes.-1983166104.timestamp
```

And the content of the file are only a `.`(dot) inside it. Anyone has any idea of how this is generated? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the project use the scala-maven-plugin?  The scala-maven-plugin adds ".<hashcode>.timestamp" to files in the target directory.  It's used for the incremental compile feature that is available for that plugin.

Comment: Thank you! I've searched a lot online but didn't find an answer, it does use scala-maven-plugin. Do you know how we can control the output?

Comment: @KevinZhou Could you accept the answer if it is correct?  I don't think there is a way to turn off the timestamp file your referring to, even if you disable incremental compile it's still created.  See https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_incremental.html

Comment: Should i just click the tick button to accept it? Thanks again for explaining this question.